# Opera и ajax

Tags: opera, ajax, php

Здравствуйте столкнулся с проблемой в опере может кто сталкивался.
Есть сайт при входе на сайт все отдается нам на php . а уже все остальные запросы обрабатывает ajax.
Проблема заключается в том что . после хоть одного запроса по средством ajax
при перезагрузки страницы опера делает ajax запросы навешанные на ссылки и получается что получаем инфу 2 раза 1 на php 2 на ajax. а если запросов не было то перезагружается нормально. кто знает подскажите как ограничить оперу от самоуправства .

Comment: следовательно google тоже.

Comment: opera 15 .

Comment: "опера делает ajax запросы навешанные на ссылки и получается что получаем инфу 2 раза 1 на php 2 на ajax" - нифига не понял

Comment: перезагружаем страницу нам выдает информацию посредством php . и тут еще происходит ajax запрос и выдает эту же самую информацию . странность в том что это происходит только если были ajax запросы а так все нормально загружает

Comment: Может в функции запроса проверять не пуст ли блок, в который будет грузится информация?